# Mouseout from div to neighboring div, keep main div open, mousout outside those divs, main div closes

Tags: jquery, html, mouseout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mouseout on specified divs and keep original div open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497880/mouseout-on-specified-divs-and-keep-original-div-open)

I asked a similar question and it got buried without any answer that solves this, so please don't flame me as I've waited and no answer works.

Here is the original question: [Mouseout on specified divs and keep original div open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497880/mouseout-on-specified-divs-and-keep-original-div-open)
Here is the fiddle all set up:
http://jsfiddle.net/bUzPG/10/

It seems like everything should work with the fiddle, but the code doesn't do what it should. Any working answer will be marked as solved, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Please stop asking duplicate questions. If you want to revise your question, just edit your original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$("#openDiv").mouseout(function (e) {
var used_classes = ['x', 'z'];
var $c = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('class');

   if ($c=='x' || $c=='z')
 {
     $("#openDiv").show().css('background-color', 'pink');
 }else{
    $("#openDiv").hide();
 }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you wanted

http://jsfiddle.net/bUzPG/16/

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you did it this way, by surrounding your 3 divs in a parent div?  http://jsfiddle.net/bUzPG/17/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to wrap the `div` elements in a parent `div` and assign the `hover()` events to that container:

html:

```
<div>
    <div class="x">x</div>
    <div id="openDiv" class="y">me</div>
    <div class="z">z</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.container').hover(
    function(){
        $('#openDiv').addClass('highlight');
    },
    function(){
        $('#openDiv').removeClass('highlight');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bUzPG/18/).

Bearing in mind that the parent `div` (or other containing element) needs to fit tightly to the bounds of the `div` elements, otherwise the `mouseleave` event won't trigger as you'd expect), which is why the `div` (but not the `div > div`s) is floated. Other options include  `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`.